# Error: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, each

I created an array through getting data from button onclick, and then I want to get this data for future ajax using. At this stage, I only want it to show up in the console:

```
fixtureArray.push(fixture);
$(fixtureArray).each(function() {
    triggerNumber = $(this).text();
    console.log(triggerNumber);
});
```

I also have tried this

```
$.each(fixtureArray, function() {
        triggerNumber = $(this).text();
        console.log(triggerNumber);
    });
```

But the console keep showing something like this:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
Sizzle.getText
Sizzle.getText
Sizzle.getText
Sizzle.getText
Sizzle.getText
Sizzle.getText
...
```

Any idea why this would happen? Thanks!

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: What is `fixture` exactly? Give us an example.

Comment: fixture would just be some numbers like '1', '2', '3'

Comment: for example: <a onclick="set('1')">...</a>, the above code will be in a function called set(num) {...}

Comment: It makes no sense to use $(this).text() for a string!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be using `$(this).text()` if it is a string, use the passed in arguments

```
var arr = ["1","2","3"];
$.each(arr, function (ind, value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I used for loop in the end and used fixtureArray[i] directly, and then I realized the problem...